# What is the meaning of the effort or velocity on urdf model

Tags: ros, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu, linear-velocity

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the meaning of these ? () on the urdf model. ı changed limit effort or velocity but nothing changed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275462/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-effort-or-velocity-on-urdf-model/) by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2017-11-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Those are documented [here](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/joint#Elements), I'll copy pasta though:

> lower (optional, defaults to 0) - An
> attribute specifying the lower joint
> limit (radians for revolute joints,
> meters for prismatic joints). Omit if
> joint is continuous.
>
> upper (optional, defaults to 0) - An
> attribute specifying the upper joint
> limit (radians for revolute joints,
> meters for prismatic joints). Omit if
> joint is continuous.
>
> effort (required) - An attribute for
> enforcing the maximum joint effort
> (|applied effort| < |effort|). See
> safety limits.
>
> velocity (required) - An attribute for
> enforcing the maximum joint velocity.
> See safety limits.

Effort is between 0 and 100 (units are %) and velocity is radians per second for revolute and continuous joints and meters per second for linear or prismatic joints.

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2017-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-09**:\

> Effort is between 0 and 100 (units are %) and velocity is meters per second.

I'm not sure this is correct: fi `velocity` is in `rad/s` for all `revolute` and `continuous` joints, while it's `m/s` for linear type joints.

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2017-11-09**:
You're right, I corrected it. Thanks.

**Comment by [Sidd](https://answers.ros.org/users/22657/sidd/) on 2019-11-06**:\

> Effort is between 0 and 100 (units are %)

I'm not sure if the effort unit is correct either. Isn't it in N? And I'm pretty sure it's not limited to 100.

**Comment by [ParitoshKelkar](https://answers.ros.org/users/24321/paritoshkelkar/) on 2020-05-07**:
"The effort limit is an attribute of the limit tag. In this case, a controller cannot command an effort of more than 30 N (N-m for revolute) nor less than -30 N (N-m for revolute) on the joint."

http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_controller_manager/safety_limits